# Find TeamCity Version/Build Number

Tags: teamcity

Is there a way to find out what version (or build number) of TeamCity I'm using from looking at the installed files? I had a quick poke around but couldn't find anything in any of the readme/batch scripts/logs etc.

The version number is normally displayed on the footer of each page, but my instance won't start, so I can't get into the GUI to see it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found a file called BUILD_27402 in webapps/ROOT. The file has no contents (0Kb), but 27402 matches the build number for version 8.0 as listed on their [previous releases page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Previous+Releases+Downloads).

So the answer is to look for that BUILD_xxxxx file in webapps/ROOT

Thanks, me. :)